# Execute PLSQL script file from RobotFramework DatabaseLibrary is throwing error

Tags: oracle, plsql, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework. I have requirement to do Data Setup in Oracle DB by running a PLSQL through "Execute Sql Script" keyword. When I execute it I am getting the following error.

Error:

```
*DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 2, column 17:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset*
```

This is the Sample PLSQL I am using, when I execute the same PLSQL in SQL Developer I don't see any syntax error.

PLSQL Script:

```
    DECLARE
   x NUMBER := 100;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      IF MOD(i,2) = 0 THEN
         INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is even');
      ELSE
         INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is odd');
      END IF;
      x := x + 100;
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Robot Script

```
*** Test Cases ***
Data Setup In Oracle
   Connect To Database      cx_Oracle    ${or-dbname}    ${or-dbuser}    ${or-dbpasswd}    ${or-dbhost}    ${or-dbport}
   Execute Sql Script       Resources/sampleplsql.sql
   Disconnect From Database
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a slash `/` to the end of the script:

```
DECLARE
   x NUMBER := 100;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      IF MOD(i,2) = 0 THEN
         INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is even');
      ELSE
         INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is odd');
      END IF;
      x := x + 100;
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
/              --> this
```

Comment: Even after adding slash / I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

All,

I found a work around to make PLSQL work with DatabaseLibrary, I have used the keyword "Execute Sql String" instead of "Execute Sql Script" and passed the complete PLSQL as a string.

I kept the PLSQL as Python variable and passed the same as argument for Execute Sql String, and it worked like a champ.

Please find the code snippet.

PLSQL.py

```
TESTPLSQL="""DECLARE
   x NUMBER := 100;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      IF MOD(i,2) = 0 THEN
         INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is even');
      ELSE
         INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is odd');
      END IF;
      x := x + 100;
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;"""
```

Robot Script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  DatabaseLibrary
Variables  ../../Resources/plsql.py

*** Variables ***
${sql-string}     ${TESTPLSQL}

*** Test Cases ***
Data Setup In Oracle
   Connect To Database      cx_Oracle    ${or-dbname}    ${or-dbuser}    ${or-dbpasswd}    ${or-dbhost}    ${or-dbport}
   Execute Sql String          ${sql-string}
   Disconnect From Database
```